# Checking if a bool is true for x seconds - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, vision

I am using VNDetectRectanglesRequest and I want to check if the CGRect of my detected rectangle is within another CGRect **for 1 second**. Here is my code so far:

```
let x = self.view.frame.width * detectedRectangle.boundingBox.origin.x
let height = self.view.frame.height * detectedRectangle.boundingBox.height
let y = self.view.frame.height * (1 - detectedRectangle.boundingBox.origin.y) - height
let width = self.view.frame.width * detectedRectangle.boundingBox.width
let rectangleDetected = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)

self.redView.frame = rectangleDetected

let outsideGuideRect = CGRect(x: self.boardMargin*1/2, y: (self.view.frame.height-self.view.frame.width+1/2*self.boardMargin)/2, width: self.view.frame.width-1/2*self.boardMargin, height: self.view.frame.width-1/2*self.boardMargin)
print(outsideGuideRect.contains(rectangleDetected))
if outsideGuideRect.contains(sudokuBoardRect) {

    // HERE I WANT TO CHECK IF THIS IF STATEMENT IS TRUE FOR 1 second

}
```

The above code is in a function that is run every frame. How could I check if the if statement is true for one second? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood form your question is, "you want to perform an action after 1 sec once your rect B come inside rect A (without leaving)".

Following can be a probable solution that I got from top of my head, there can be something better to this, if we think little more.

```
//initialize _insideRect as false globally
if outsideGuideRect.contains(sudokuBoardRect) {
    // HERE I WANT TO CHECK IF THIS IF STATEMENT IS TRUE FOR 1 second
    if (!_insideRect) {
      _insideRect = true;
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(0.1)) {
        if (_insideRect) {
          // your function here
        }
      }
    }
}else{
    _insideRect = false;
}
```

Comment: While this does work, is it better than the solution proposed above?

Comment: I believe my understanding of the question is different than Rakesha's he have suggested in his solution action is suppose to fire if other event happened within 1 sec of first event. And my solution is for the case where rectB remain inside RectA for 1 sec. As you can see, after 1 sec if your rectB is still inside Rect A (despite all the movement) event will take it's course. And there can be multiple trigger if user choose to go in and out of the rect several times,.